# Use lambdaj library in android development

Tags: java, android, lambdaj

Is there any way to use [the lambdaj library](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) in android development ?

Comment: @ARV..have you found the solution for this case in android.If so let me have your suggestion.. I'm getting success while implementing with java but can't get the same in android while using the same code base and libraries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383219/android-search-from-large-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be about size  of lambdaj jar.(750kb). Is ıt make sense to try to use it in mobile environment. Try to reduce size  by removing common loggins and unused classes from hamcrest and cglib.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this by importing the. jar file in the lib folder of the project.