# Android : Search from Large Arraylist

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I have a recordset of about 29,000 records. My Screen contains EditText Box for Search Criteria and Listview containing all 29,000 records.

By searching with the listed way it takes time and not giving flow less output as I need.

My EditText contains

```
final EditText txtSearchCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCity);
        txtSearchCity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                aCountryIDTemp.clear();
                aCityStateTemp.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < aCountryID.size(); i++) {
                    if (aCityState
                            .get(i)
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .contains(
                                    txtSearchCity.getText().toString()
                                            .toLowerCase())) {
                        aCountryIDTemp.add(aCountryID.get(i));
                        aCityStateTemp.add(aCityState.get(i));
                    }
                }

                BindList();
            }
        });
    }
```

BindList() method is setting the arraylist aCityStateTemp to adapter.
Any Other way to Search and Create new ArrayList dynamically.

Comment: Better you use the database and execute LIKE query when Edit-text text changed.

Comment: @Dharmendra was doing the same instead of this.. but taking the same time..

Comment: @Vishal Khakhkhar I am using custom key pad to give input to edittext but I am facing delay while pressing button faster I have 1000+ records .How I can Improve please help

Answer (score 14):

I would insist to use [**Lambdaj**](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)  Library which is mostly used in such cases where you want to restrict loops for sorting and filtering Collections.

Here is a small example for using lambdaj for filtering `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String> sortedArrayList = select(arrList, having(on(String.class),
                                                   Matchers.containsString("a");
```

This will return a complete filtered `ArrayList` with which you want to populate your `ListView`.

You can also `filter` Custom Classes - [**Java: What is the best way to filter a Collection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385698/726863)

**UPDATE:**

Above solution was `case-sensitive` so to work around you can add [**Multiple Matchers**](http://saturnboy.com/category/work/).

Like this you can add `Multiple Matchers`,

```
ArrayList<String> sortedArrayList = select(arrList, having(on(String.class),
   (Matchers.anyOf(Matchers.containsString("a"),Matchers.containsString("A")))));
```

**UPDATE:**

Even better way is to use `filter(Matcher<?> matcher, T...array)`

Here is how you can do that,

```
ArrayList<String> sortedArrayList = filter(Matchers.anyOf(
           Matchers.containsString("a"),Matchers.containsString("A")), arrList);
```

Also, if you are interested in using some of the methods/features of `lambdaj`, you can extract the source and get it working. I am adding the same for `filter()`

You can just download [`hamcrest-all-1.0.jar(63 kb)`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all) and add below code to get the `filter()` working

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(Matcher<?> matcher, Iterable<T> iterable) {
    if (iterable == null)
        return new LinkedList<T>();
    else{
        List<T> collected = new LinkedList<T>();
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        if (iterator == null)
            return collected;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T item = iterator.next();
            if (matcher.matches(item))
                collected.add(item);
        }
        return collected;
    }
}
```

So, you can just sort out the least from `lambdaj` source and integrate in your source.

Comment: Superb library +1 Mr Poptani.

Comment: A very good library but sadly it doesn't work with Android. I saw the following link before I gave up. Despite that, I'll keep it as an option for non-Android projects if I ever need to. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16528057/1276636

Comment: What is Matchers for this library ? I found error in Matchers function.Please explain it

Comment: public static <T> List<T> filter(Matcher<?> matcher, Iterable<T> iterable) {
     if (iterable == null)
         return new LinkedList<T>();
     else{
         List<T> collected = new LinkedList<T>();
         Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
         if (iterator == null)
             return collected;
         while (iterator.hasNext()) {
             T item = iterator.next();
             if (matcher.matches(item))
                 collected.add(item);
         }
         return collected;
     }
 }

Comment: ArrayList<Products> sortedArrayList = (ArrayList<Products>) filter(Matchers.anyOf(
             Matchers.containsString(searchText),Matchers.containsString(searchText.toUpperCase())), productList);

Comment: Please check my two comments, the size of new list is always zero.

Comment: @MohammadRajob prefer asking a seperate question with your source code

Comment: @LalitPoptani Please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988831/android-arraylist-filter-with-hamcrest-jar

Answer (score 2):

You can use HashSet or LinkedHashSet(keeps insertion order) for fast searching.
With contains() method of that classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you have passed `aCityStateTemp` to you `Adapter` as `ArrayList` while initializing the `Adapter`

Now after changing the contents of `aCityStateTemp`, you just need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. you don't need to set the `aCityStateTemp` to adapter as new `ArrayList`.

Comment: Adil.. I wasnot doing as the way you suggested but now I have tried with changing the way you suggested. infact adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is a good way to refresh the adapter so have did it. but taking the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all data in a sqlite database and retrieve the searched item using like query.

Comment: I was doing the same before.. but it was taking the same time.. so used this approach.