# Search filter for an Arraylist

Tags: android, search, android-arrayadapter, android-edittext

This is my code snippet:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence changed_character, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
        if(search_adapter != null)
        {
            search_adapter.getFilter().filter(changed_character.toString().trim());
        }
    }
```

So, here I am filtering the arraylist based on the text changed in my edittext box.
Suppose I enter "A", it filters all the items containing A in it. I just want to retrieve and list items "starting with" A. How do I do this?

Comment: check google's guava library: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter(java.util.Collection, com.google.common.base.Predicate)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383219/android-search-from-large-arraylist/10396356#10396356

Answer (score 0):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:completionThreshold="1"
/>


public class AndroidAutoCompleteTextView extends Activity implements TextWatcher{

AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;
String item[]={
  "January", "February", "March", "April",
  "May", "June", "July", "August",
  "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.myautocomplete);

       myAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(this);
       myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,         android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));

   }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
  int after) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```