# Updating listview android on textchanged StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview, textchanged

I'm having trouble with updating my listview ontextchanged. When I enter one letter works fine, but on the second letter the app crashes. What can be the problem?
I've tested and the dolzina or length is correct but why on the second inserted character in the edittext the app crashes? Can the adapter be a problem? 
Here is the code!

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<Son> sonovi;
    private EditText filterText = null;
    private SonovnikAdapter adapter;
    private ListView list;
    Translator t = new Translator();
    private Intent intent;
    private ArrayList<Son> temp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initStuff();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                intent.putExtra("opis", sonovi.get(position).getOpis());
                intent.putExtra("naslov", sonovi.get(position).getNaslov());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                int dolzina = filterText.length();
                temp = new ArrayList<Son>();
                temp.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < sonovi.size(); i++) {
                    if (filterText.getText().toString().toLowerCase()
                            .equals((String) sonovi.get(i).getLatinicno()
                                    .toLowerCase().subSequence(0, dolzina))) { //line 63
                        temp.add(sonovi.get(i));
                    }

                }

                SonovnikAdapter testc = new SonovnikAdapter(Main.this,
                        R.layout.item, temp);
                list.setAdapter(testc);
                testc.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        intent.putExtra("opis", temp.get(position).getOpis());
                        intent.putExtra("naslov", temp.get(position)
                                .getNaslov());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });

    }

    private ArrayList<Son> readTxt() {
        ArrayList<Son> s = new ArrayList<Son>();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sonovnik);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String str = null;
        String naslov, opis, latinica;
        String[] tmp;
        try {
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tmp = str.split("-");
                naslov = tmp[0];
                opis = tmp[1];
                if (tmp.length >= 3) {
                    latinica = tmp[2];
                    s.add(new Son(naslov, opis, latinica));
                }
            }
            is.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s;
    }

    private void initStuff() {
        list = getListView();
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        sonovi = new ArrayList<Son>();
        sonovi = readTxt();
        intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
        adapter = new SonovnikAdapter(this, R.layout.item, sonovi);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    }

    private class SonovnikAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Son> {

        private ArrayList<Son> items;

        public SonovnikAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Son> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            Son o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                TextView naslov = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                if (naslov != null) {
                    naslov.setText(o.getNaslov().toString());
                }
            }
            return v;

        }
    }
}
```

And the output from logcat:

```
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1651)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:2040)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at com.sonovnik.petkovski.Main$2.onTextChanged(Main.java:63)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6321)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6362)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6511)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:502)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:415)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:318)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:75)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
05-07 15:16:58.770: E/AndroidRuntime(31689):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: change this  int dolzina = filterText.length(); to  int dolzina = filterText.getText().toString.length();

Comment: @ZazGmy did that but not working,the error is same

Comment: instead of using dolzina = filterText.length();  you use "s" which is use as a parameter in onTextChange listener

Comment: like dolzina = s.toString().length();

Comment: @ZazGmy nope still not working :(

Comment: Have some Useful Links [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result/8678198#8678198) and [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383219/android-search-from-large-arraylist/10396356#10396356) :)

Answer (score 1):

Your elements are not of the same size. You are assuming that every element in sonovi (getLatinicno) has at least dolzina characters. But readTxt doesn't do any control of this kind.

Comment: Thera are many ways. For example you can do try{}catch StringIndexOutOfBoundsException{ //do nothing, because sonovi(i) is to short to be equal to filterText.getText()}