# How to update the listview after the search of the items in android

Tags: android, listview, search, filter

Currently i'm working on How to find the items from the listview when given the keyword for the item in edittext, now my "*find*" function is working correctly but displaying the found items in toast message, and the listview positioned items remains the same, how to update my listivew to get the filtered results in it.
Here's my code

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

//how many to load on reaching the bottom
int itemsPerPage = 15;
boolean loadingMore = false;                        

//For test data :-)
Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();

ArrayList<String> songsList;
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
JSONArray posts;



//ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;
LayoutInflater inflater;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://india.abc.net/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";    
static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
    //this will be used in the custom adapter
    inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   // Creating JSON Parser instance
   final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

   // getting JSON string from URL
       JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }


              //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);


         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);

             searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                   String searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                   int textLength=searchString.length();

                          //clear the initial data set
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                  String playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){

                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength)))
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),playerName,1).show();
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));

                  }
                   }

                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {

                   }

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                   }
                  });
```

**adapter class:**

```
  public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  TextView title;
  private Activity activity;
  // private TextWatcher textWatcher;
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}


public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date); // artist name
    TextView content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.content);  // duration
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);



    // Setting all values in listview
   title.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_TITLE));
    date.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_DATE));
    content.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_CONTENT));
    name.setText(song.get(Home.KEY_NAME));

   imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(Home.KEY_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}


public void add(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8678198/726863 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10396356/726863

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: hi Anukool i hv used that tutorial also, but thy hv not mentioned wat code to be placed in filter@Anukool

Comment: thanks for ur reply lalit but m getting error in "get" as "The method get(String) is undefined for the type String" can u pls help me to solve this error... @LalitPoptani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### replace the code within searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

} 
by

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                    searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                    textLength=searchString.length();
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                   playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();
                  System.out.println("player name "+playerName);
                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){
                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                    if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength))){
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                    System.out.println("the array list is "+songsList.get(i));
                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, searchResults);   

                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                      }


                   }
                   if(searchResults.isEmpty()){
                       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "No Items Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                                  toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                                  toast.show();
                   }
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {
                 System.out.println("before changed");

                   }

                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                                               System.out.println("after changed");
                   }
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone through your code but by looking at your question i think you have to update your `listview` when you type text in your edit text so you have to do it like this set `addTextChangedListener` to your `EditText` and put your search function in `afterTextChanged` method then just do this

```
 MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.listview1, string_array);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

at the end it will work.

Comment: i have to set my code in filter, but the fact is i tried to do, but getting error:( @Auto-Droid

Comment: check if your filtering is properly working because refreshing the listview is not that difficult to be problematic