# Android arraylist filter with hamcrest jar

Tags: android, arraylist, hamcrest

I have an android project, which have an custom object array list, now I want to filter that array list. But always I get zero (size of new array list).

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(Matcher<?> matcher, Iterable<T> iterable) {
    if (iterable == null)
        return new LinkedList<T>();
    else{
        List<T> collected = new LinkedList<T>();
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        if (iterator == null)
            return collected;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T item = iterator.next();
            if (matcher.matches(item))
                collected.add(item);
        }
        return collected;
    }
}

ArrayList<Products> sortedArrayList = (ArrayList<Products>) filter(Matchers.anyOf(
               Matchers.containsString(searchText),Matchers.containsString(searchText.toUpperCase())), productList);
```

Why I am getting zero, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `matcher.matches(item)` in the filter method  returns always `false` because you have string matchers (`Matchers.containsString`) but `item` is of type `Products` (assuming that `productList` contains items of type `Products`).

`Matchers.containsString` returns a matcher which inherits form `TypeSafeMatcher` and checks that the matched value has a compatible type. So it expects a `String` but get a `Products` object.

I see two options:

- Change `matcher.matches(item)` to `matcher.matches(item.getText())` where `getText` extracts the relevant string to match (you have to adjust the generics `<T>` -> `<T extends Products>`).
- Create a `FeatureMatcher`

  ```
  public class ProductsTextMatcher extends FeatureMatcher<Products, String> {

      public ProductsTextMatcher(Matcher<? super String> subMatcher) {
          super(subMatcher, "", "");
      }

      @Override
      protected String featureValueOf(Products actual) {
          return actual.getText();
      }

  }
  ```

  and call it like so:

  ```
  filter(new ProductsTextMatcher(
          Matchers.anyOf(Matchers.containsString(searchText), Matchers.containsString(searchText.toUpperCase()))),
          productList);
  ```